# Converting empty string to $null back to the same variable

Tags: powershell

We have a few imports via PowerShell in to Active Directory that have a couple fields that come across as an empty string from the datasource, but need to be set as `$null` within Active Directory.

Since there are quite a few of these fields, I attempted to create a function that will convert an empty string to `$null`.

The trouble is that if I set the variable back to itself, it remains an empty string. If I set it as a new variable, it works fine.

```
function Get-ValueOrNull
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [string]$Value
    )

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Value))
    {
        return $null
    }

    return [string]$Value
}

function Test-Function
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [string]$TestValue
    )
    $TestValue = Get-ValueOrNull -Value $TestValue
    $TestValue2 = Get-ValueOrNull -Value $TestValue

    Write-Host "TestValue: $($TestValue -eq $null)"
    Write-Host "TestValue2: $($TestValue2 -eq $null)"
}

Test-Function -TestValue ""
```

Here the output is

```
PS C:\> .\Test-Function.ps1
TestValue: False
TestValue2: True
```

This is clearly something I'm not understanding about Types in PowerShell function parameters. I can change the `[string]$TestValue` to `$TestValue`, and it will work.

```
function Test-Function
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        $TestValue
    )
    ...
}
...
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> .\Test-Function.ps1
TestValue: True
TestValue2: True
```

The reason I'd like to preserve the `[string]` parameter type is to enforce that it should be a string or an empty string. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've casted the *variable* as opposed to the *value being assigned* you are strictly typing that variable.

This is easier to see with an `[int]` because basically anything can be casted to a `[string]` successfully:

```
$v = [int]'5'
$v.GetType()  # int

$v = 'hello'
$v.GetType()  # string

[int]$v = '5'
$v.GetType()  # int

$v = 'hello'
# Exception:
# Cannot convert value "hello" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

When you type a parameter, the variable that contains the parameter is the same way; you can reassign it, but the right side must be assignable / castabale / convertible to the left side's type.

A `$null` cast as `[string]` is an empty string:

```
([string]$null) -eq ([string]::Empty)  # True
```

You can still strongly type your parameter, if you use a different intermediate variable in the function that isn't, as you demonstrated with `$TestValue2`.